# Check if each value in a dataframe column contains words from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I iterate through each value in one dataframe column and check if it contains words in another dataframe column?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['the cat jumped over the hat', 'the pope pulled on the rope', 'i lost my dog in the fog']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'dirty_words': ['cat', 'dog', 'parakeet']})

a    
    text
0   the cat jumped over the hat
1   the pope pulled on the rope
2   i lost my dog in the fog

b
    dirty_words
0   cat
1   dog
2   parakeet
```

I want to get a new dataframe that contains only these values:

```
result

0   the cat jumped over the hat
1   i lost my dog in the fog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `any` after splitting strings by whitespace. This method won't include "catheter" just because it includes "cat".

```
mask = [any(i in words for i in b['dirty_words'].values) \
        for words in a['text'].str.split().values]

print(a[mask])

                          text
0  the cat jumped over the hat
2     i lost my dog in the fog
```

Answer (score 3):

Use regex matching with `str.contains`.

```
p = '|'.join(b['dirty_words'].dropna())
a[a['text'].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format(p))]

                          text
0  the cat jumped over the hat
2     i lost my dog in the fog
```

The word boundaries ensure you won't match "catch" just because it contains "cat" (thanks @DSM).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. This solution works on the pseudo code I posted here, but on my real data I received the following error message: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-d9101ca2d009> in <module>()
----> 1 p = '|'.join(dcstreets['REGISTEREDNAME'])

TypeError: sequence item 12: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @silverSuns Try again

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `isin` after `str.split`

```
a[pd.DataFrame(a.text.str.split().tolist()).isin(b.dirty_words.tolist()).any(1)]
Out[380]: 
                          text
0  the cat jumped over the hat
2     i lost my dog in the fog
```